# Polyfill Set in TypeScript but "Set is not defined"

Tags: typescript, polyfills

I have `es6` as one of the options in `compilerOptions.lib` in `tsconfig.json`, so I would assume that makes `Set` available in TypeScript (2.8.1).  Most browsers work but some do not---I'm still logging Android and UC Mobile browsers that are generating this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Set is not defined
```

I added Set from [polyfill.io](https://polyfill.io/v2/docs/features/#Set) but that doesn't seem to make a difference:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Set"></script>
```

Is there a way to polyfill Set in the rest of these browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems cdn.polyfill.io doesn't recognize User-Agent of these devices. According to [docs](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/docs/api) - you can force to return default polyfill if User Agent is unknown with **unknown** request parameter:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Set&unknown=polyfill"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and see if it clears up the error logs.  It looks like the `unknown=polyfill` [breaks the UC Desktop Browser](https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service/issues/1702) but that's a separate problem.

Comment: That fixed that, but now it hits more UC Browser problems.  Looks like an exceptionally buggy browser.

Comment: Polyfill.io does not support either mobile or desktop UC Browser, and setting `unknown=polyfill` creates all kinds of other errors.  I switched to importing the polyfills myself.